# Como substituir determinadas letras duma frase?

Tags: lua

Eu quero substituir essas letras:

```
local words = {"v", "s ", "#@#", "s", "รง", "b", "mp", "t"}
```

Quando elas tivessem em uma frase seriam substituídas, ou pode ser uma tabela assim também:

```
local words = {
   ["v"] = "d",
   ["s"] = "k"
}
```

Supondo que tenho a frase `Insira o texto`, o resultado desejado seria `infira o fexfo`, substituindo o `s` e `t` por `f`.

Comment: Você pode [editar a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/66562/edit) e colocar um exemplo do que pretende fazer?

Comment: Digamos que esse é o texto : "Insira o texto", iria retornar isso "infira o fexfo"

Comment: Isso seria em que linguagem?
De qualquer maneira tens de percorrer a string como um array, e confirmares se é essa letra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a [função `string.gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/pt/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) para fazer as substituições, o padrão `%a` representa todas as letras:

```
function substituirLetras(texto, traducoes)
    return string.gsub(texto, "%a", traducoes)
end
```

Para utilizá-la, faça:

```
-- chave: o valor a ser substituído
-- valor: o substituto
letras = { 
   ["s"] = "f",
   ["t"] = "f",
}

texto = "Insira o texto"

resultado = substituirLetras(texto, letras)
print (resultado) -- Infira o fexfo
```

[Ver **`demonstração`**](http://ideone.com/euT5ko)

Comment: Isso mesmo cara muito obrigado

Comment: @JoaoGabriel Disponha. Se possível marque a resposta como aceita, clicando na marca ✔ abaixo da pontuação. =)